# AS400 DB2 View Created with IBM SQL Nav Locking File In Use

Tags: db2, locking, view, ibm-midrange, sql-navigator

I've searched for days trying to find a solution and couldn't find any so I've decided to reach out to the community.  I'm a Windows Programmer and I'm not familiar with the DBA programming and commands within the AS400.

I created several views that are just simply select statements of production tables.  They were created with IBM SQL navigator which I like to use for most things because I'm not familiar enough with the AS400 to do it from the database green screen directly.  I received a complaint by a director that I was causing some problems for him with the views I've created.  He states my views are locking the tables and the AS400 will not allow him to re-org the file while it was in use.

He said if he were a DBA he wouldnt allow me to do what I did.  I'm at a loss in that I've created thousands of views over the years but with SQL Server not AS400.  Not allow me to create a SQL view seems to me like someone whose not very experienced at handling this issues within the database.

I'm asking for some basic help to preventing the locking of tables for re-orgs etc. by creating views in sql navigator.    I created the view using iSeries SQL Navigator and simply adjusted the permissions of the view after I created it.  Did I do something wrong and is there something I need to do to prevent locking?

UPDATE: There is a ASP.NET application that queries the views to throw into an Excel reports and emails them out.  That application closes the connection when the job is completed.

Comment: If the director was a DBA, he possibly wouldn't need to re-org the tables; the tables might then be defined so that it might be unnecessary. The RGZPFM command requires **exclusive** use unless ALWCANCEL(*YES) and either LOCK(*EXCLRD) or LOCK(*SHRUPD) are specified as command parameters. But ALWCANCEL(*YES) requires the table to be journaled, and I'd guess they aren't since the director is not a DBA. A VIEW isn't needed if you're only reading from the table. Why did you create them?

Comment: The views were created because the queries were complex resulting a the combination of several queries.  Rather then hard coding these queries and bloating the program with having to read in the results of multiple queries within the application the views were the best solution and the fastest.  The views work well.  I will use the commands provided to check on the locks and see if I have a problem where the open connection to those views are not closed as expected.

Comment: Good enough reasons. Of course, the locks would be the same either way; so your director's complaint is that the queries are run at times when exclusive access is desired. It's irrelevant whether VIEWs are used. If you have database authority to create VIEWs, there should be no basis for a complaint since they make no (locking) difference.

Comment: I guess I'm screwed now.  I presented my plan to him and he tells me corp has a source control product and these wont migrate to it and it will also error the rebuild function.  He states I have no reason to create files this way.  He's going to force me now to recreate dozens of views now on the AS400.  Some are complex sql statements.

Comment: Source control is a separate issue. If "corp" mandates that it be used, then copy/paste your views into the source control app and promote it -- assuming that you have authority to that action. If you don't then it needs to be done by someone who does or you need to have the queries in your external program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a view doesn't create a lock.

However, reading a table directly or through a view does just like it would in MS SQL Server.

You don't mention how you're reading the views, from a program or from some a SQL tool such as SQuirreL or IBM's Run SQL Scripts.  If from a program, you need to make sure you're properly closing the result sets / connections  I've seen lots of bad code that doesn't close result sets/connections properly; a real problem if connection pooling is also being used.

Assuming result sets and connections are being closed properly, the other issue is what's called pseudo-closed cursors.  For performance reason, by default once the system has done a full open 3 times for a given cursor (open data path (ODP)), the system will stop fully closing it when asked to.

This causes problems for operation that need exclusive access to the table.

Actually, it only causes problems when the operations aren't willing to wait for the system to automatically fully close the ODP.  Depending on the operation, the willingness to wait is controlled by the Maximum file wait time (WAITFILE) parameter on the table and/or the Default wait time (DFTWAIT) time of the job.

You can also manually request that the system fully close any pseudo-closed ODP on a table by using the Allocate Object command like so:

```
ALCOBJ OBJ((MYLIB/MYTABLE *FILE *EXCL)) CONFLICT(*RQSRLS)
```

For more info on pseudo-close cursors, see this IBM doc [Pseudo Closed Cursor FAQ](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/entdocview.wss?uid=nas8N1017851)

Couple of options

1. Make sure that operations are willing to wait..

   - CHGPF FILE(MYLIBIB/MYTABLE) WAITFILE(1)
   - CHGJOB DFTWAIT(30)
2. Manually force the pseudo-closed cursors closed using the ALCOBJ as above

Finally, consider stopping the use of commands from the 1980's when everybody went home at 5pm.

Instead of needing to use RGZPFM, change the table to reuse deleted records.

```
CHGPF FILE(MYLIB/MYTABLE) REUSEDLT(*YES)
```

Instead of CLRPFM, use and SQL DELETE statement.

Comment: I'm wondering if I could execute the queries that use the views as read only.  Would that remove the lock?  I can't go at my director with the AS400 information because I cant tell you that it will be seen as if I'm undermining him.  I would like to use an ASP.NET approach to avoid the record locking issue.

Comment: 1. IIRC physical file reorganisation needs exclusive file access, which means even an opened read-only access would block it.
2. Check if your director means the `RGZPFM` command or deletion/renaming of the physical file. Created views prevent these actions , no matter if a job is using it or not.

Comment: No, ready-only wouldn't help.  The lock is a result of the ODP the system uses to read the records being left open for future reads.

Comment: @Mike, you can look at the locks using the WRKOBJLCK command.  If there are some, and you run the ALCOBJ command shown in my answer and they don't disappear, then your ASP app is not closing the result set.

Comment: I will check on these locks.  I'm guessing with SQL server the DBAs never had any reason to keep re-orging tables like my director is doing.  I've never had the issue in the past until I started working with DB2 AS400 databases an for this company.  I'll start watching these locks and see if I can detect the source

Comment: MS SQL Server arguably requires reorgs for peek performance.  In contrast, DB2 for i reorgs are a legacy left over you should be getting rid of.

Comment: CREATE VIEW necessarily locks all table-references, but they are short-lived; released before VIEW has finished creating. Additionally, Maximum File Wait Time (WAITFILE) should never play a role in locks held by pseudo-closed, except lock escalation to implement isolation-level RR, but that's irrespective of pseudo-close, but requesters will not signal a close-event [i.e. no Request-Release notification asking to resolve the conflict]. And only non-SQL *operations* should be impacted by resolvable conflicts [i.e. job with locks can close]; such ops are what ALCOBJ CONFLICT(*RQSRLS) is for